# Query based parameter routing Google load balancer - IAP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iap

Recently, I was testing Google https load balancer with query based parameter routing, after configuration, I found that I'm not able to activate IAP on any backend services except default backend , none of backend appeared in IAP.

For http, as per documentation, it's working fine but still no backend (except default)appeared in IAP.

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-query-and-header-routing

Does anyone face such issue? Any thoughts - I would appreciate.
Thanks,adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior seems to be a UI bug.  There is a freshly created bug on Issue Tracker you may keep an eye on:

https://issuetracker.google.com/161689238

As a workaround, IAP can be enabled manually, so that overcome UI misbegavior.

After [configuring](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-query-and-header-routing#gcloud_6) an URL map, IAP for the second service can be enabled by following the steps [Enabling IAP using Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-compute-howto#enabling_iap_sdk) to activate IAP for all backends manually.